# Delete html tags from PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, curl, get, html-parsing

I wanna delete some words from simple_html_dom  when get external data (e.g name of Author or name of website )  from this code:  `

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

include('simple_html_dom.php');  
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Create DOM from URL or file


$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');       

$myContent = $html->find('table', 0)->plaintext;
echo $myContent;
```

I don't know how can do it (delete flowing code from a table from url)

```
  <tr style="background: #ffd700;color:black;">

    <td colspan="5">**delete this words from table..**   
    </td></tr>
```

Comment: Maybe see this answer, should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691175/simple-html-dom-parser-to-return-all-tds-values

Comment: please tell me more I couldn't set a value to my problem

Answer (score 1):

you can also delete directly from the dom the innertext between your TD

```
$html->find('table tr')->children(NUMBER OF THE TD TO EMPTY)->innertext = '';
```

here is the doc for simpleHtmlDomParser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm grabbing a table, and needed to remove the tfoot. Did so like:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = str_get_html($curl_response_html); // load html from string
$wtable = $html->find('table[id=sometableid]',0); // get table by id
$wtable->find('tfoot',0)->outertext=''; // find the element in the table and remove it
echo $wtable;
```

In your case, if you want to remove the whole row and you know the table row number, you can do something like:

```
$wtable = $html->find('table[id=sometableid]',0); // get table by id
$wtable->find('tr',0)->outertext=''; // find the element in the table and remove it
```

Where `'tr', 0` that would remove the first row, and `'tr', 3` would remove the fourth row.

Or even:

```
$wtable = $html->find('table[id=sometableid]',0); // get table by id
$wtable->find('td[colspan=5]',0)->innertext=''; // find the element and remove its contents
```

That would get the first cell with colspan 5 and remove its contents.

Answer (score 0):

there is a table here I'm going to delete this td `<td colspan="5">` all html files is here:

```
    <table cellspacing="6px" border="0px" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="670px" style="font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;font-family:times new roman;margin-top:0px;border:1px solid #666666;text-align:center;">
<tbody><tr><td colspan="4">text 1
</td></tr><tr style="background: #ffd700;color:black;">

<td colspan="5">text for delete‌   
</td></tr><tr style="background: #fdfdad">
<td colspan="5" style="font-size:13pt;">text2
</td></tr><tr style="background: #ffffcc">
<td colspan="2">text3
</td><td>text4
</td><td>text5
</td></tr><tr style="background: #fdfdad">
<td width="35px"><img src="PIC/PNG/UnitedStates-01.png" width="33" height="22">
</td><td>text6
</td><td>3015
</td><td>2990
</td></tr><tr style="background: #ffffcc">
<td><img src="PIC/PNG/Europe-01.png" width="33" height="22">
</td><td>text7
</td><td>4100
</td><td>4072
</td></tr><tr style="background: #fdfdad">
<td><img src="PIC/PNG/Canada-01.png" width="33" height="22">

</td><td>2436
</td><td>2366
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

How to delete a td from a table in the simple_html_dom ?

Comment: Using this as an example  // Find all td tags with attribite align=center in table tags  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)
$es = $html->find(''table td[align=center]');  Your example would need something like this  $html->find('table tr td[colspan=5]')->innertext = '';